# Tensorflow2 Tensorboard is not working in jupyter (static ip)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, static-ip-address

I Want to see it Tensorflow Graph and Weight using Tensorflow **in Jupyter Notebook**. 
But It is not working.
I use Jupyter notebook on the remote server.

`%tensorboard --logdir logs`
`%load_ext tensorboard`

[image]

it say it is too long to response at static ip.

How can I solve it?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorboard Not Running Properly on port 6006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983776/tensorboard-not-running-properly-on-port-6006)